# Slow fetch on private queue ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

I have the following Core Data Stack:

1. A main NSManagedObjectContext with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`
2. Multiple temporary `NSManagedObjectContexts` (created on demand) with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. Their parent managedObjectContext is set to the main managedObjectContext

So far I used the main managedObjectContext for fetching and the private managedObjectContexts for data imports because there is quite a lot of data to be saved and I don't want to block the main thread. So far this has worked very nice for me.

Now I want to implement a full-text search for my app searching through of a lot of data. I understand that this is computationally expensive and therefor I want to do this in the background.

```
- (void)filterConfigurationsInBackground
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[MVADataManager sharedInstance] privateContext];
    [temporaryContext performBlock:^{
       NSArray *filteredConfigurationsObjects =
       [temporaryContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
       NSArray *filteredConfigurationsObjectIDs = [filteredConfigurationsObjects valueForKey:@"objectID"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[MVADataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    [mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in filteredConfigurationsObjectIDs)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSManagedObject *configuration = [context existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&error];
        if (configuration == nil)
        {
            DLog(@"Invalid objectID: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            [result addObject:configuration];
        }
    }

    [self setFilteredConfigurations:result];

        if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] == 1)
        {
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        [self updateTitle];
    }];
}];
}
```

This does work, but the fetch is really slow and the UI freezes which obviously shouldn't happen. My understanding is, that since I perform the actual fetching and filtering on the private queue, the main thread shouldn't be blocked at all. Time Profiler is no help and just shows 99% running time of "main". Why does this code block the main thread?

### Update 1

By setting breakpoints I identified that the fetching of the objectIDs is the part of the code that slows everything down. While at the breakpoint the debugger shows that we're on a background thread, the UI freezes. The CPU report in Xcode shows, that all the work is done on the main thread

### Update 2 and Workaround

I found a workaround for this problem but I still have no clue what exactly would be the cause for it. I discovered that Core Data seems to struggle with my rather complex compound predicate for the full-text search. (Aside from the full-text search my predicate does also some basic filtering on these objects.)

So if I first perform the core data fetch with just the basic filtering predicate, and apply the full-text search predicate part afterwards via `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, everything gets nicely done in the background without blocking the main thread. I still have no idea why this problem persists but I'm content with this workaround for now. Until I have time (and the nerves) to look deeply into that I leave this question unanswered.

Comment: How many items in `filteredConfigurationsObjectIDs`?  If those objects have not been registered with the main context before, the context will have to fetch each one individually in your for loop.  Try fetching with an IN predicate to get them all in one go.

Comment: And in the first fetch, on the temporary context, you could set the fetch request's `returnType` to `NSManagedObjectIDResultType` to avoid the `valueForKey`.

Comment: Thanks for the tipps pbasdf! I will implement these and report my results. I have currently about 300 objects to fetch (not including relationships)

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but the fetching is still really slow.What particularly bothers me is, that the fetching of the objectIDs is what seems to be the part that slows the app down. The UI freezes and the fetch is performed on the main thread instead of in the background

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what to suggest.  What about having the temporaryContext go straight to the PSC?